# Perl Regex Multiple Matching with Nagiosgraph

Tags: regex, perl, nagios

I'm working with Nagiosgraph trying to create a regex to match multi-line output data from a Nagios plugin and I cannot get it to output more than the first match. I've tried with and without the /g modifier as well and numerous other suggestions that various people have posted in other discussions but still haven't got anywhere.

The data I'm working with is in the format of:

```
    output:DISK: C - WARNING : Percent Used : 85.5% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 49.9 GiB, Used : 42.7 GiB,  Free : 7.2 GiB
    DISK: C(id: 1) - WARNING : Percent Used : 85.5% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 49.9 GiB, Used : 42.7 GiB,  Free : 7.2 GiB
    DISK: D(id: 2) - OK : Percent Used : 13.7% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 84.6 GiB, Used : 11.6 GiB,  Free : 73 GiB
    DISK: E(id: 3) - OK : Percent Used : 19.6% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 418.6 GiB, Used : 82.2 GiB,  Free : 336.3 GiB
```

And the regex I'm using is:

```
    /.*?DISK: (\w)[(]id: [.0-9]+[)].*?Percent Used : ([.0-9]+%).*?/g
```

All I want is the disk ID and % used for every line with an "id" value but when I run through the resulting vars it only ever matches the first instance ("1" & "85.5%").

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The regex seems sound, the issue probably has something to do with *how you use it*, e.g. how you get the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

This worked for me. I modified your statement to include the case insensitive option `i` and it started working. I also and added a start of string anchor to force the regex engine to only match the string at the start of a each line

## Perl Code Example

```
$string =  <<END;
output:DISK: C - WARNING : Percent Used : 85.5% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 49.9 GiB, Used : 42.7 GiB,  Free : 7.2 GiB
DISK: C(id: 1) - WARNING : Percent Used : 85.5% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 49.9 GiB, Used : 42.7 GiB,  Free : 7.2 GiB
DISK: D(id: 2) - OK : Percent Used : 13.7% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 84.6 GiB, Used : 11.6 GiB,  Free : 73 GiB
DISK: E(id: 3) - OK : Percent Used : 19.6% (WARN: 85% / CRIT: 95%), Total : 418.6 GiB, Used : 82.2 GiB,  Free : 336.3 GiB
END
while ($string =~ m/.*?DISK: (\w)[(]id: [.0-9]+[)].*?Percent Used : ([.0-9]+%).*?/ig ) {
print "id = $1, Percent = $2\n";
```

## Output

```
id = C, Percent = 85.5%
id = D, Percent = 13.7%
id = E, Percent = 19.6%
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the regex is more or less correct (as you pointed out) but the problem is coming from a discrepancy in the way that Nagiosgraph's Test Script processes data compared to the live version.

The test script parses the whole of the output whereas the live seems to stop at the first carriage return, which is why it was only returning one result. I modified the output that was being sent to remove the carriage returns and the regex is now working correctly.

Comment: Excellent. On this site, you should submit that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I couldn't answer my own question for 8 hours after submitting.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the regex was correct (as was pointed out) but the problem was coming from a discrepancy in the way that Nagiosgraph's Test Script processes data compared to the live version.

The test script parses the whole of the output whereas the live seems to stop at the first carriage return, which is why it was only returning one result. I modified the output that was being sent to remove the carriage returns and the regex is now working correctly.